# Удаление элемента DOM на сервере

Tags: html, jquery

Дорогие друзья! У меня к вам вопрос - У меня есть структура документа:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

внутри каждого элемента списка, находится таблица, я добавил к иконке внутри таблицы метод .remove() (jquery). Все работает отлично, но после перезагрузки страницы таблица снова появляется. Как правильно удалить таблицу средствами Jquery, чтобы она больше не появлялась? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: открыть файл на html-шаблона  на сервере и удалить (закомментировать) руками ненужный текст

Comment: А как выполнить это программным путем?

Comment: Средствами `jQuery`? `ajax` запросом, на хэндлер, который бы удалял `html` разметку в соответствующем шаблоне. Ну, либо собственно написать код на сервере, покуда тот на `js` крутится. Ну а вообще, без шуток, править шаблон, как и сказали ранее. Не обязательно что-либо удалять, достаточно просто не включать эту таблицу в вывод.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В даном случае нужно сохранять состояние в базу данных или в куки( но даже в случае с куки это создает привязку только к браузеру), если вам это подойдет. В любом случае `$("li").remove();` изменяет DOM в браузере. Обычно в таких задачах присутствует серверная технология (к примеру [`php`](http://php.net/) и другие) и база данных (к примеру [`mysql`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)).
Да. И `ajax` технологию тоже было  бы неплохо, чтобы удалять без перезагрузки страницы. Короче говоря здесь нужен полный Stack Web технологий чтобы зделать так, как это делается на современных сайтах.

Comment: Значит, noSQL приложение сделать не получиться?

Comment: Полностью взглянуть на код вы можете тут https://github.com/Vankalif/script_mon

Comment: `и база данных (к примеру mysql).` Я говорю за любую базу данных и noSql (к примеру mongoDb) тоже база данных

Comment: я думал создать приложение в обход баз данных, в проекте, который указан выше, она(БД) просто не требуется.

Comment: NoSQL (англ. not only SQL, не только SQL), в информатике — термин, обозначающий ряд подходов, направленных на реализацию хранилищ `баз данных`, имеющих существенные отличия от моделей, используемых в традиционных реляционных СУБД

Comment: В любом случае нужна серверная технология которая будет заталкивать данные пусть даже в `noSql`